# noobs reset password Debian

Tags: debian, noobs

Hello I'm a Raspberry Pi newbie and It seems that I lost my password.

I was trying to ssh but unable to because of  password problems. Connecting pi to my TV, I can get to the command prompt #, but I am still unable to change the password. I tried creating a new user but got error 10

I don't want to do too much because I seem to have root access at the pi itself.

Again the Debian install with noobs

Answer (score 4):

1. Put your (micro)SD card into a computer
2. Copy `cmdline.txt` to `cmdline.txt.bak` (just to make a backup)
3. Open `cmdline.txt` and add this to the end of the line: `init=/bin/sh`
4. Put SD card back into Raspberry Pi and turn it on
5. You should have root shell and you will be able to change password for any user, eg. `passwd pi` or `passwd root`
6. Remove `init=/bin/sh` from the end of the `cmdline.txt` or just delete that file and rename `cmdline.txt.bak` to `cmdline.txt`
7. Reboot RPi

---

Another method, taken from: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=121407

> On the Noobs screen with a keyboard attached, press ctrl-alt-f2 and logon with username=root password=raspberry
>   mkdir -p /media/boot
>   mount /dev/mmcblk0p5 /media/boot
>   cd /media/boot
>   Then use vi to edit the file directly.
>   (i to enter insert mode, Esc : w q to save & exit when done)

Comment: The only partition I can see on the SD card is Recover

Comment: you can try this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=121407

Comment: @MikeAlberga You need to plug your SD card in a linux running box, windows or mac os doesn't read ext partitions by default unless you have any utilities installed.

Answer (score 1):

No need to edit cmdline.txt file. Mine is Raspberry Pi 3 with Noobs Raspbian OS.

Steps:

1. Connect Rpi3 to HDMI interface
2. You will get UI ( no password prompt)
3. open terminal
4. sudo su (will not prompt password)
5. passwd pi
6. enter new password

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change the root/user password by editing the `/etc/shadow` file when you plug the SD card into another computer (running linux), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534693/linux-set-root-password-on-etc-shadow-file).

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this today using Raspian Stretch with NOOBS. I tried the solutions listed here but they did not work. Here's what worked for me

- Put your (micro)SD card into a computer
- Open the BOOT drive
- Copy cmdline.txt to cmdline.txt.bak (just to make a backup)
- Open cmdline.txt using NotePad++ or another unix-aware text editor
  add this to the end of the line: `init=/bin/sh`  NOTE WELL: ADD TO THE END OF THE EXISTING LINE. DO NOT PUT THIS ON A NEW LINE
- Save the file
- Put SD card back into Raspberry Pi and turn it on
- It will get partway through the boot process and then stop. There is no command line prompt, but you will be now type a command
- type: the following: `mount -o remount,rw /`   Pay attention to spacing
- type: `passwd pi`
- type: `sync`
- type: `exec /sbin/init` (this resulted in an error for me but the password change remained in effect_
  Remove `init=/bin/sh` from the end of the cmdline.txt or just delete that file and rename cmdline.txt.bak to cmdline.txt
  Reboot RPi